# How to access and modify a sibling of a Tcl/Tk object in R

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit, tcltk

**In short:**

I use `tcltk` package in R. But non-R users may suggest ideas too and provide examples in other language than R.
I have a list of Tcl/Tk objects in R `<Tcl> .1.1.1.1 .1.1.1.2 .1.1.1.3` and want to access and modify each object separately. How can I do it?

Or If I have button A object, how can I access and modify button B object?

**Details:**

I have the following widget:

[image]

The code to create it:

```
library(tcltk)

top <- tktoplevel()

frame_1 <- tkframe(top)
tkgrid(frame_1)

frame_n <- tkframe(frame_1)
tkgrid(frame_n)

b1 <- ttkbutton(frame_n,  text = "button A")
b2 <- ttkbutton(frame_n,  text = "button B")
b3 <- ttkbutton(frame_n,  text = "button c")
tkgrid(b1, b2, b3)
```

Let's say I can access only `b1`:

```
class(b1)
# [1] "tkwin"
```

I want to access and modify the siblings of `b1` as if I had objects `b2`, etc. (for example):

```
tkcget(b2, "-text")             # Get text
tkconfigure(b2, text = "New B") # Change text
```

By using `tkwinfo`, I managed to access the parent of `b1` and get a list of siblings (I'm not sure if technically it is a "list"), but I don't know, how to access/modify each of them one by one:

```
(parent_of_b1 <- tkwinfo("parent", b1))
# <Tcl> .1.1.1 

(siblings_of_b1 <- tkwinfo("children", parent_of_b1))
# <Tcl> .1.1.1.1 .1.1.1.2 .1.1.1.3 

class(siblings_of_b1)
# "tclObj"
```

My attempt results in error:

```
tkcget(siblings_of_b1, "-text")
# Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj") : 
#   [tcl] invalid command name ".1.1.1.1 .1.1.1.2 .1.1.1.3".
```

Most probably I don't know the way to subset the object. How can I do it?

---

**UPDATE:** based on the comments of @Donal Fellows, I found the solution.

Function `as.character()` does the job.

```r
(my_tcl_object <- tkwinfo("children", parent_of_b1))
# <Tcl> .1.1.1.1 .1.1.1.2 .1.1.1.3
```

```r
as.character(my_tcl_object)
## [1] ".1.1.1.1" ".1.1.1.2" ".1.1.1.3"
```

In this situation, `tclvalue()` + `strsplit()` works as well:

```r
strsplit(tclvalue(my_tcl_object), " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
## [1] ".1.1.1.1" ".1.1.1.2" ".1.1.1.3"
```

But, in general (for other problems), `as.character()` vs. `tclvalue()` + `strsplit()` may give different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `winfo children` subcommand (using the underlying Tcl name) returns a *Tcl list of widget identifiers*. In general, this is a bit messy to deal with from other languages (because of potential issues with handling quoting rules) but because the generated widget identifiers just contain ASCII digits and `.` characters and the separators are just single spaces, simply [splitting by space](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) will give you the right thing.

```
(siblings_of_b1 <- strsplit(tkwinfo("children", parent_of_b1), " ", fixed = TRUE))
```

You'll need to iterate over the resulting list, of course. Multiple siblings are multiple siblings. (Also, don't forget that this *includes* b1 itself; you've not asked for the actual siblings, but rather the children of the parent.)

Comment: Good ideas. Just please, fix code to `(siblings_of_b1 <- strsplit(tclvalue(tkwinfo("children", parent_of_b1)), " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1]])` as current version results in error:
> `Error in strsplit(tkwinfo("children", parent_of_b1), " ", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument`

Comment: `as.character()` is a shorter solution than `strsplit()`.