# How to access all activate tk window IDs (path names) in R console?

Tags: r, tcl, tcltk

Suppose I create several tk windows but do not assign them to any real objects.

```
library(tcltk)
# two activated tk windows
tcl('toplevel',".foo")
tcl('toplevel',".bar")
```

Is it possible to access their IDs (or path names) by executing some function `f()` so that two "tclObj" objects are returned or a string (`c(".foo", ".bar")`) could be returned?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54042767/how-to-access-and-modify-a-sibling-of-a-tcl-tk-object-in-r seems relevant, as long as you get the children of the `.` window.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it should be

```
tkwinfo("child", ".")
```

In R